# Date compare java fail

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

while comparing future days it occurs some fail in Java. Look at the code if you can

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("2258-11-01");
Date date1 =  dateFormat.parse("2258-10-31");
System.out.println(date.after(date1));
```

Output is:`false`

Anyone has idea why it does't work?

Comment: You should use `yyyy-MM-dd`, month character is invalid, `m` is for minutes, so you were using january first, and january 31st with 00:11, and 00:10 respectively, check [here](https://help.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/date-and-time-format.html) for pattern syntax

Comment: Documentation is your friend: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

The `m` format represents a minute in the hour. You probably meant to use `M`, representing the month in the year:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the capital MM for month, overwise it does not parse like you want it to.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use the modern [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes to [parse your strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) that happen to be in [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
LocalDate.parse( "2258-11-01" )
.isAfter( 
    LocalDate.parse( "2258-10-31" ) 
)
```

> true

## Details

As others mentioned, the formatting pattern is case-sensitive, and yours is incorrect.

Another problem, you are inappropriately squeezing a date-only value into a type intended for a date with time-of-day in UTC.

Also, you are using the terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Your input strings happen to comply with the excellent [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to even bother with defining a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.parse( "2258-11-01" ) ;
LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.parse( "2258-10-31" ) ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean isAfter = ld1.isAfter( ld2 ) ;  // true
```

All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Please learn to search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).